# Relation of screen size and data usage

Tags: multiple-monitors, internet

I want to know if there is any relation between data usage and screen size. I found some dat online but it was mostly done on laptop screen sizes. I want to know if I connect my laptop to a monitor, then what happens. I have connected my Mac to a 27" monitor.

So will my wifi data consumption increase in this case?

Comment: What are you planning to use on WiFi? Is it browsing webpages? is it Remote Desktop to another device? It really depends on what you are going to do if it will effect your wifi data consumption at all.

Answer (score 1):

To answer this question, it doesn't really matter what monitor or resolution you use. The only thing that really matters is what you will be doing with it.

If you connect to another pc, the higher your resolution can be, the higher it will be when connecting to the other pc, if you use software that scales according to your resolution, such as Microsoft Remote Desktop Connection (mstsc). Because the resolution is higher, more pixels are transferred to your pc, and thus more data is consumed.

When it comes to other things, such as streaming videos, browsing webpages, these are all related to the settings you use when browsing them, not how big your screen is. A 720p video will still be the same on a small screen as on a big screen. It can be possible for a webpage such as youtube to switch you to a higher quality, but it will only do so if you have it set to auto, the screen resolution is sufficient to matter AND the internet speed is sufficient too. This can still be overwritten from your settings, so I count this as a: this won't change. There are always exceptions to the rule, but they are fairly exceptional.

A webpage loads in its entirely when you visit it, and is shown to you as you browse the page, so the data remains the same.

One could argue that with more pixels on your screen, you can have more programs open that all use the internet at the same time, and yes, if you use more programs, then obviously you use more data. But lets say that you keep using the same programs as you already do now. If that is the case, only software to VIEW/control another REMOTE desktop is going to have effect on your bandwidth and thus your wifi data.

Answer (score 0):

Screen size has no impact on data usage. They are two entirely different things.

One video stream or web content source running on a computer with a single small monitor uses exactly the same amount of network data as that same video stream or web content running on a computer with 2, 3, 8, 12 large screens connected to it.

There may be correlation though: On a multi-monitor setup you may be more likely to have several types and sources of content running simultaneously, and therefore you'd use more network data, but that is a function of the volume of content you are consuming, not of the number or size of the screens you are consuming it on.

Comment: Also, larger monitors cause people to use higher resolution streaming settings in my admittedly limited experience.

Comment: Once again that is a function of the content, not the screens. OP is asking if adding a screen to his Mac will increase his data usage. So long as his computer use remains the same, the data will remain the same. Any such link is correlation, not causation.

Comment: If you RDP into another pc, a higher resolution means you get more data. So yes, this is one of those exceptions to the rules, which is why I posted my comment on the question in the first place....

Comment: We can probably agree that, as it is written, the question is too broad.

Comment: No it isn't. Because if OP is not doing any kind of remote connection to another system, then the answer is always no.

Comment: @music2myear - I understand that and agree with you. I was providing another example along the same lines as your multi-monitor example.

Comment: @LPChip - Then for this one user it is not too broad. I always evaluate questions based on the person that is going to stumble on it in a year. Who know what that person is going to be doing.

Comment: @EBGreen I've posted an answer of my own because it is really simple. This should satisfy your curiosity for other users as well.